# hyperledger-fabric peer0 environment

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am very new to this subject and I have to go through a fabric-sample.
But at this point I have problem
[Environment variables](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#environment-variables)

```
# Environment variables for PEER0

CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
```

But my docker-compose-base.yaml file has the following lines

```
environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
```

When I run this command

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

I have this error message

```
INFO 004 MSP configuration file not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/config.yaml]: [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/config.yaml: no such file or directory]
```

I am sure this error message cased by the missing/different lines in my docker-compose-base.yaml

What could I do in this case?
Just put these lines in my file?
Or something has gone wrong at some point what I did not realize?

Please bear with me as I just have started.

Thank you

edit: I have this error message

```
Error: Got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST
Usage:
  peer channel create [flags]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That's not an error message, but an INFO one.
an MSP can be configured to have an OU by having that config file with the following fields in it:

```
OrganizationalUnitIdentifiers:
  - Certificate: "cacerts/cacert.pem"
OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: "COP"
```

It's perfectly fine not to have this file and to see this INFO message.

Comment: Thank you Now I see it is an INFO. Could you check the last few lines in my question? I have added them just now as I forgot about this.

Comment: Yeah. Regarding the error - can you take a look at the ordering service log? it will explain why you received the error.

Comment: Could you help me where the log file is located or how to get it from CLI?

Comment: docker ps and then docker logs orderer0 (assuming orderer0 is your orderer container name. maybe it will be something like orderer.example.com)

Comment: Thank you I have the logs now `Error reading from stream: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled` and this one `Error reading from stream: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled` I had to use this command `docker exec -it cli bash` and I can not see any log information since I ran this one.

Comment: If you got a BAD REQUEST on the client side you will surely see some warning in the ordering service log... this one isn't it.

Comment: I have uploaded a picture of the docker logs to my question

Comment: can you try with a different channel name? Could it be that the channel already exists?

Comment: I have tried but I have got the same error. The network works fine until I need to update the environment variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148511/discussion-between-laszlo-peter-varga-and-yacovm).

Comment: I think that it happens because you have a previous channel configuration located in the orderer. Try to remove your Docker containers and start up again the network.